# Shade background in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, backgrounds, shading

I am using pgfplots package. I tried to use shade axis background. It is working in the .dvi output... But I don't see the shade when I convert it into pdf.
Can anybody tell me the reason?

I use TeXnicCenter editor...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}
\tikzset{every mark/.append style={scale=1.1}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogyaxis}[axis background/.style={
shade,top color=blue!10,bottom color=white},
legend style={fill=white},
legend style={at={(0.03,0.03)},
anchor=south west},
title=Convergence Plot,
xlabel={SNR (dB)},
ylabel={Symbol error probability},
grid=major,
legend entries={A  ,B ,C },
]
\addplot+[mark =square*]  coordinates{
 (0,0.0463972) (2.5,0.0182014) (5,0.00574787) (7.5,0.000925764) (10,0.000129722) (12.5,1e-006)
};;
\addplot+[mark=triangle*]  coordinates{
 (0,0.0915691) (2.5,0.0562446) (5,0.0313533) (7.5,0.0177173) (10,0.011644) (12.5,0.00576422)
};
\addplot  coordinates{
(0,0.056353) (2.5,0.0283069) (5,0.0132647) (7.5,0.00345943) (10,0.000725631) (12.5,6.96066e-006)
};
\end{semilogyaxis}grid=major,


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: With version `1.8`, compiling with `pdflatex` works for me. Did you try also that way?

Comment: how do you convert the dvi to pdf? If you use dvips, it should work right away. Any other dvi-to-pdf converter will need to be configured in the preamble of your document, otherwise the resulting pdf might be corrupt/have broken graphics.

Comment: With no feedback on the two questions, we can't really give more help. Please edit-in the appropriate info and request reopening.